# Is there a security problem with having two factor auth running on the same machine that's requesting access?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

Searched around and couldn't find a similar question.

I've gotten tired of waiting for an 2FA SMS to come every time I check my email. So I got to setting up an app similar to say Google Authentication on my desktop, so that when I get prompted for a code I can just copy/paste from my toolbar.

I can see how this basically defeats the 2FA purpose though right?

Comment: Why would it defeat the purpose? What purpose are you seeing in 2FA?

Comment: Usually I would think if 2fa as requiring another device that pages me. If the code is right there in the corner what good does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not defeat 2FA. If someone steals only your password, or if you use the same password everywhere and it leaks, the second factor will still protect your account.

That's the purpose of 2FA: add another layer of security. Having both on the same device does not change that. That "one-password-for-everything" is still secured by 2FA anyway.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess usually 2fa is implemented by bringing in another device (yubikey, cell phone app, ect) it seemed wrong to have them both in the same place.